# Neo4j - Spring Data Neo4j - Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store version

Tags: neo4j, pom.xml, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to open graph db using neo4j but constantly get this error after trying couple of workarounds.

- *To enable automatic upgrade, please set configuration parameter "dbms.allow_format_migration=true"*
- changing neo4j-kernel version in pom.xml

here are my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there any way to overcome this issue.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @BrunoPeres this is what i get when I try to start Neo4j on the repository containing db **:**

 _Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store version. To enable automatic upgrade, please set configuration parameter "dbms.allow_format_migration=true"_

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are opening a database created in an older version of Neo4j with a newer version of it.

You have 2 options to solve it:

1. Downgrade Neo4j version to the older version.
2. Find and open the file `neo4j.conf`, find the line with `bms.allow_format_migration` and change this value to `true` (`bms.allow_format_migration=true`). The file location depends on what SO are you running. Take a look [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/).

Comment: option 2 is not working and I have other another project that works on my current version of Neo4j. Downgrading it will disturb that. Is there any way to configure my Pom.xml in spring framework to current version of Neo4J